# isalpha()? or others... debug assertion failed, circlemud game

Tags: c++, assertion, isalpha

**Please excuse me for using the translator.**

**I'm a beginner in programming.**

The decades-old circlemud is being modified. Although it is already localized and can be implemented in VC6.0 without any problems, there is a problem in the entry of Korean names as it moves to VS Community 2019.

The game is so old that most of the community in Korea has disappeared, so I couldn't find help and visited the place.
I wish I could speak English well, but...

Entering the Korean language (CP949 or?) will cause the ishanalp() to crash.
When I added /J and compiled it, there is no crash in the Korean input, but I cannot recognize the Korean name.

Removing the isalpha() part will allow access to the game, but a crash will occur in the area where the name is printed or stored.

debug assertion failed!

File; isctype.cpp
Line: 36

### expression: c >= -1 && c < 255

```
#define ishan(ch) (((ch) & 0xE0) > 0x90)
#define ishanasc(ch) (isascii(ch) || ishan(ch))
#define ishanalp(ch) (isalpha(ch) || ishan(ch))
#define isnhdigit(ch) (!ishan(ch) && isdigit(ch))
#define isnhspace(ch) (!ishan(ch) && isspace(ch))

int _parse_name(char *arg, char *name) 
{
int i;
/* skip whitespaces */
for (; isnhspace(*arg); arg++);
     for (i = 0; (*name = *arg); arg++, i++, name++)
         if (!ishanalp(*arg)) // here debug assertion failed line 36
             return 1;
         if (!i)
            return 1;
            return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ishanalp(static_cast<unsigned char>(*arg))` should fix it, same change for the call to `isnhspace`.

It's little known that the `is...` character classification functions don't take `char` arguments but instead take an `int` argument that must have an **unsigned char** value or be `EOF`. If `char` is a signed type (as it typically is) and you have a negative value then the `is...` function can fail.

I'd also recommend recoding those macros as inline functions.